# How to exit from .out file to add string to stdin?

Tags: c++, linux, bash, g++

I'd like to add every line to stdin, but I can't because a.out doesn't exit from loop.

C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::string in;
  
  while(1){
    std::cin >> in;
    if(in == "exit")
      break;
    std::cout <<in << "\n"; 
  }
  return 0;
}
```

And a bash code:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r line
do
  echo "$line" | ./a.out >> output.txt
done < "input.txt
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your C++ program already has the required loop. Why put yet another loop in your shell script? Just do ```./a.out < input.txt > output.txt```

Comment: Your C++ program is executed once for each line in the input file. Unless every line contains the word`"exit"`, the stream will enter an error state and your program gets stuck.

Comment: By the way: you are aware that formatted extraction with `>>` doesn't read line by line, right?

Answer (score 0):

your C++ part works perfectly. But as soon as it exits, you again do while read -r line. Try to enter EOF just after "exit" line.